# HLS Media Segment Time Range

Tags: http-live-streaming

Is there a way to specify a start time and/or end time for a media segment?

I have 2 playlist files and I am trying to keep each playlist's total duration lower or equal to 30 sec long. If the last media segment of the 1st playlist exceeds the 30 sec duration, the segment should end shorter. The 2nd playlist file will recognize the shortened segment from the previous playlist and play its remaining duration at the start of the playlist.

`playlist1.m3u8`

Total Duration: **31.779 sec**

**segment_0p0002.ts** needs to be shortened by **1.779 sec**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:11.819000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-01-12T18:21:06.695+0000
segment_0p0000.ts
#EXTINF:9.980000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-01-12T18:21:18.514+0000
segment_0p0001.ts
#EXTINF:9.980000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-01-12T18:21:28.494+0000
segment_0p0002.ts
```

`playlist2.m3u8`

Total Duration: **31.158 sec**

**segment_0p0002.ts** needs to continue its last duration of **1.779 sec**

**segment_0p0004.ts** needs to be shortened by **1.158 sec**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:9.980000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-01-12T18:21:28.494+0000
segment_0p0002.ts
#EXTINF:9.980000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-01-12T18:21:38.474+0000
segment_0p0003.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-01-12T18:21:48.454+0000
segment_0p0004.ts
```

I tried shortening the **#EXTINF** duration for **segment_0p0002.ts**, but that doesn't change the playlist duration.

I tried using the **#EXT-X-DATERANGE** tag for **segment_0p0002.ts**, but that also didn't work.

```
#EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="999",START-DATE=2022-01-12T19:21:18.394+0000,DURATION=1.779000
```

Answer (score 0):

`START-DATE` should be a quoted attribute, to me it seems:

```
  START-DATE

  A quoted-string containing the ISO-8601 date at which the Date
  Range begins.
```